# Property 'insertRule' and 'deleteRule' does not exist on type 'StyleSheet'

Tags: javascript, typescript

The code is used to check if a CSS Pseudo class is supported by the browser. It works fine in JavaScript but throws up errors in Typescript. Below is the typescript code:

```
var supportsPseudo = function(pseudoClass) {
      // Get the document stylesheet
      var ss = document.styleSheets[0];

      // Create a stylesheet if one doesn't exist
      if (!ss) {
        var el = document.createElement("style");
        document.head.appendChild(el);
        ss = document.styleSheets[0];
        document.head.removeChild(el);
      }

      // Test the pseudo-class by trying to style with it
      var testPseudo = function() {
        try {
          if (!/^:/.test(pseudoClass)) {
            pseudoClass = ":" + pseudoClass;
          }
          ss.insertRule("html" + pseudoClass + "{}", 0);
          ss.deleteRule(0);
          return true;
        } catch (e) {
          return false;
        }
      };

      // Run the test
      return testPseudo();
    };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this `CSSStyleSheet` interface to specify the type of `ss`, 
Here is a [link](https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/interfaces/_node_modules_typedoc_node_modules_typescript_lib_lib_dom_d_.cssstylesheet.html) to for reference.

Comment: Thank you. This is my first time of working with typescript, Can you please show me how?

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I did this:  ```var ss = <CSSStyleSheet>document.styleSheets[0];```